Working with Llama 3.2 Vision Multimodal for Object detection using roboflow
So I am working on a project where I am using a dataset downloaded from Roboflow in yolo format and then I am trying to pass the training folder to Llama 3.2 for supervised learning on that dataset from the hugging face transformers but the issue is that it starts on the training but most of the time it just stops on it own with no errors.
I have tried different methods for fine tuning it but none of them have worked.
I have also shared a snippet of my fine-tuning method for Llama and currently it keeps going into error during training.
And below is the format for my roboflow dataset:
Yolov8 format for dataset
def train_llama(images, descriptions):
    print("Initializing model and processor...")
    model_id = "meta-llama/Llama-Guard-3-11B-Vision"
    
    # Initialize processor
    processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id)
    
    # Initialize model
    model = AutoModelForImageTextToText.from_pretrained(
        model_id,
        torch_dtype=torch.float16,
        device_map="cuda"
    )
    model.config.use_cache = False

    print("Creating dataset...")
    dataset = CustomImageTextDataset(images, descriptions, processor)

    # Split dataset
    train_size = int(0.9 * len(dataset))
    val_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    train_dataset, val_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])
    print(f"Train size: {train_size}, Validation size: {val_size}")

    # Training arguments
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir="./llama_finetuned",
        learning_rate=1e-5,
        num_train_epochs=3,
        per_device_train_batch_size=2,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
        warmup_ratio=0.05,
        logging_steps=10,
        eval_strategy="steps",
        eval_steps=50,
        save_strategy="steps",
        save_steps=100,
        fp16=True,
        gradient_checkpointing=True,
        remove_unused_columns=False,
        report_to="tensorboard",
        load_best_model_at_end=True,
        metric_for_best_model="loss",
        dataloader_num_workers=0
    )

    # Initialize trainer
    trainer = CustomTrainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=val_dataset
    )

    print("Starting Llama training...")
    try:
        trainer.train()
        print("Training completed successfully!")
        
        print("Saving model...")
        trainer.save_model("./final_llama_model")
        print("Model saved successfully!")
        return True
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during training: {str(e)}")
        print(f"Traceback: {traceback.format_exc()}")
        return False


Kindly provide the complete code.
